# my Web API C#.net server is not able to Deserialize JSON Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

This my client code

```
var sayeed = { firstname: "Sayeed", surname: "Alquiaty" };
alert(JSON.stringify({ person: sayeed }));
$.ajax({
    url: "api/parent",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ person: sayeed }),
    success: function(response) {
        response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
    }
});
```

At the Server side

```
public class Person {
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

//Here I am able to receive object but is is not FirstName = null and Surname = null
// POST api/parent
public bool PostParent(Person person) {
    return person != null;
}
```

So the client get a success message but actually  JSON Object is not Deserialize

I have tried other method like using JObject but that is currupting the Json object, what i mean is it is converting the client object as Key and the then adding : "". Which is not what i want.

Comment: What happens if you just post "{'firstname':'Sayeed','surname':'Alquiaty'}"

Comment: Hi Nick, I tried that, so that makes my person object as null.

Comment: And what if you capitalize your parameter names in the first line like so:
     var sayeed = { Firstname: "Sayeed", Surname: "Alquiaty" };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your code:

1. The deserialization is case sensitive, so the properties on JS side must have the same case that the properties on the server side
2. You need to pass the person object as parameter directly, not included as the `person` property of an object
3. although it generally doesn't hurt, you do't need to stringify the object. jQuery `ajax` will do it automatically for you

In regards to 1, you can setup the Web API serializer to convert server side PascalCase to client side camelCase, and viceversa, but you still need to take this into account when converting the property names between client and server side:

```
var jsonformatter
  = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

jsonformatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver
  = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Comment: Thanks JotaBe, these are really valuable bit I will try this again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for trying to help me resolve this issue.
But I could discover the bug in my server side code it is this

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = false;
```

So now I commented the above config setting and every thing started working perfectly. But this took me 2 days to really figure out the real cause(supposedly)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forgot to mention that I have made small change to PostParent(JObject result) so the result is able to receive the JSON object deserialized correct. Then I can create a person object from it. Hope this is helpfull